# My program doesn't work when I enter it in the terminal

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a calculator program using standard input redirection, but for some reason my code doesn't load anything when I try it. The calculator program should compute expressions involving addition, subtraction, and the notation X^ which stands for X^2.

In my text file, I have the formulas

```
5^;
1000 + 6^ - 5^ + 1;
```

and my code is

```
int main()
{
    int answer, num;
    char sign;
    cin >> answer;

    while (cin >> sign)
    {
        if (sign == '^')
        {
            answer = answer * answer;
        }
        else if (sign == '+')
            {
                cin >> num;
                cin >> sign;
                if (sign == '^')
                {
                    answer += num * num;
                }
                else
                {
                    answer += num;
                }
            }
             else if (sign == '-')
             {
                cin >> num;
                cin >> sign;
                if (sign == '^')
                {
                    answer -= num * num;
                }
                else
                {
                    answer -= num;
                }
             }
                else 
                {
                    cout << answer << endl;
                    cin >> answer;
                }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you always get a string, you can examine what is in the string and make a decision.

Comment: Read `char`s in 1st place, check if they're digits, and place the digits into a string, you can convert to an `int` if all input is done.

Comment: There is a name for the problem that you're trying to solve. It's called parsing.

Comment: All input is a set of characters.   Your program (or library functions you use to read the input) determine how it is interpreted (e.g. as an integral value).

Comment: dont use >>, use cin.getline, to read whole line into a string then work down the input characters at a time

Comment: " "cin >> next" to get the next input, how do I know if the next input is" No; the "next input" - meaning the thing that `cin >> next` reads - has the type of the `next` variable. C++ is a statically typed language after all. There isn't a decision to make at this point. What you're *actually* asking about, presumably, is how to *decide which variable to read into*. The short version is: just get a word of input as a string, then look at that string and decide how to convert it.

Comment: FYI -- If that expression gets even slightly more complicated with multiplication, division, or parentheses, you basically have to start all over again from scratch, as the code you wrote now won't be able to help you.  Just a warning, and hopefully this task doesn't expand to attempt to do those other operations.

Answer (score 2):

You always read a string. Better embrace that. From that point on, you need to [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) the expression. So, if your language only allows 1 line expressions, read the whole line:

```
std::string line;
getline(std::cin, line);
```

Then parse the string and evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not sure what you are getting at as not enough information was given, but this is my attempt on trying to answer your question as accurately as possible):

When you declare any variable you must put the data type first:

`int next;`

or

`char next = 'a'; //or whatever letter you want to declare here`

`char` only works for singular letters based on the ASCII values ([ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)).

It would greatly help if you post some code to provide more context to your problem, so that way users know what your specific problem is in order for us to provide you with the best suggestions/solutions possible!